# What is meaning of unit (mg-Pt/cm^2) in relation to fuel cells?

Tags: physical-chemistry, units

I do not understand what the meaning is of the unit

mg-$\ce{Pt}$/cm$^2$

which I have come across in reading about the theory of fuel cells.

In simple terms, what does this unit mean?

Comment: Milligrams of platinum per square centimeter.

Comment: This isn't really homework, is it close voters? It's just a misguided asker.

Answer (score 3):

The unit in question means milligrams of platinum per square centimeter.

In your application - fuel cells, and specifically the membranes used to fabricate them - it describes how much of the metal is present per square centimeter of membrane.